# Avoiding multiple calls to autofocus in material-ui <TextField> component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

This question is related to `material-ui` `<TextField>` component, however the solution is likely to be found in React itself.

Imagine we're doing a simple login form. The login form is represented by a state machine.

```
{
  empty: {},
  filled: { typing, authenticating }
}
```

I have a `<LoginForm>` component which renders two `<TextField>` components and a `<Button>`. The first `<TextField>` autofocuses on mount. Pretty simple.

I have a parent component that manages the current state of the machine, and renders different components based on its value, as follows:

- empty: `<Empty>` component which renders the `<LoginForm>` with certain props
- filled: `<Wrapper>` component - equivalent to `<Fragment>`

Any of the states under `filled` are rendered as a child of `<Wrapper>`.

- typing: `<Typing>` component which renders `<LoginForm>` with different props
- authenticating: `<Authenticating>` component which renders a spinner.

`empty` state transitions to `filled` when *one* of the `<TextBox>` components are no longer empty.

---

**Problem:**

Imagine we start in the `empty` state. It renders `<Empty>` which renders `<LoginForm>` which renders username `<TextField>` with autofocus.

We have focused on the username input and start typing. All is good.

However imagine we started typing in the password first (i.e. the 2nd `<TextBox>` that doesn't autofocus). We start in the `empty` state, write the first letter of our password, transition to `filled>typing` state which seems to remount `<LoginForm>` and autofocus once again to username input. The result is that you can write the first letter for the password, and subsequent letters get added to the username input due to the re-autofocus.

I figured since the markup produced by react is essentially the same (by virtue of wrapper components with no rendering of their own) that there would be no re-mounting, and thus we only get the autofocus on first mount (i.e. when starting in `empty`).

How might I resolve this?

Comment: What's your reason for switching parent from Empty to Wrapper based on the values of the text fields?

Comment: By design, my generic `<MachineDelegator>` renders a container component for hierarchical states and injects the concrete state components into it. Since `filled` is hierarchical, its container is a `<Wrapper>` and the child states (e.g. `<Typing>`) are rendered inside it. I could make the container optional.

Comment: I think you're nonstandard use case makes this task near impossible.  Changing parent requires a remount. The only think I can think of (which is horribly hacky), is to store which TextField was last interacted with.

Comment: Yes, that hack is something I wanted to avoid. I also tried passing in a prop to `<LoginForm>` for autofocusing, but when it's set to `false` the remount will cause both inputs to lose focus instead of wrongly focusing on username.

Comment: Given my nonstandard use case, I think a solution will require extending `<MachineDelegator>`. If I made it possible to pass in a function to generate a react element, then `<Typing>` (for instance) would not need to be inserted as a node. Only the element it produces would be inserted. Obviously this would only be possible to do with stateless components.

Comment: Yes, I resolved my issue by allowing `<MachineDelegator>` to render three kinds of 'renderables' - a react component, a react element, and a function producing a react element. Doing this I was able to ensure the 'component hierarchy' stayed intact

Answer (score 0):

Before (problematic code):

```
const LoginMachineDelegator = () => {
  const props = {
    machine: init.machine,
    render: {
      [init.STATES.EMPTY]: Empty,
      [init.STATES.FILLED]: Wrapper,
      [init.STATES.TYPING]: Typing,
      [init.STATES.AUTHENTICATING]: Authenticating
    }
  }

  return <MachineDelegator {...props}/>;
}
```

React component tree when in `empty` state:

`MachineDelegator > Empty > LoginForm`

React component tree when in `filled>typing` state:

`MachineDelegator > Wrapper > Typing > LoginForm`

---

After (reconciled code):

```
const LoginMachineDelegator = () => {
  const props = {
    machine: init.machine,
    [init.STATES.EMPTY]: { func: createEmptyLoginForm },
    [init.STATES.FILLED]: { /* no element */ },
    [init.STATES.TYPING]: { func: createTypingLoginForm },
    [init.STATES.AUTHENTICATING]: { component: Authentication }
  }
}
```

Because the functions return a react element, they themselves do not get inserted into the React component tree. Instead the returning element is. As such, the new component tree would look like this:

When in `empty` state:

`MachineDelegator > LoginForm`

When in `filled>typing` state:

`MachineDelegator > LoginForm`

---

This ensures that the LoginForm does not get re-mounted and re-rendered